# Positive SemiDefinite Matrix. Theory vs Matlab

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

For my problem, I am looking for *optimal vector $q$* that minimizes **mean squared error (MSE)** that has a form $$MSE=q^{T}(R_{xx}-R_{yx}^{T}R_{yy}^{-1}R_{yx}^{})q^{}.\tag{1}$$

Since $MSE\geq0$, it turns out that $P=R_{xx}-R_{yx}^{T}R_{yy}^{-1}R_{yx}^{}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. Note that $R_{xx}^{}, R_{yy}^{}$ are correlation matrices and $R_{yx}^{}$ is a cross-correlation matrix.

I know that solution to eq(1) comes from eigen value decomposition of $P$.

However when I try to implement in MATLAB, some of the eigen values of $P$ are coming out to be negative. Can someone please point out how should I go about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you simply seeing the effects of finite precision in floating-point numerics?

Simple MATLAB example. This should trivially be positive semidefinite

```
x = ones(10,1);
X = x*x';
```

but it is not in floating-point numerics

```
>> min(eig(X))
ans =
 -2.3078e-16
```

Comment: @ Johan, Thank you for your answer. Your example fits my problem. Since I am supposed to be picking the eigen vector that corresponds to smallest eigrn value, I am confused about how to fix this floating-point numerics problem.

Comment: Also, if I use svd(P) instead eig(P), I don't see any negative singular values. I am just trying to understand how theory and matlab implementation are different and how to make choices when implementing in matlab

Comment: Sometimes its the other way round. Some singular values are negative while eigen values are all positive. Since there is no pattern here, matlab implementation of theory looks challenging

Comment: How large are the differences between eig and svd? Is the $P$ that you obtain indeed symmetric?

Comment: They are very close in magnitude. Sometimes if singular value is very close to zero, then the corresponding eigen value becomes negative. I checked symmetry of my matrix by norm(P-P',inf), and it comes out to be a very small number like e-15. But it is not zero. I googled and found this https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42885-nearestspd/content/NearestSymmetricPositiveDefinite/nearestSPD.m but I am getting into same negative eigen values for the new matrix  as well

Answer (score 0):

Since $P=R_{xx}-R_{yx}^{T}R_{yy}^{-1}R_{yx}^{}$ is the Schur complement of the block matrix
$$
R:=\left[
\begin{matrix}
R_{xx} & R_{yx}^T \\
R_{yx} & R_{yy}
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
(w.r.t. the block $R_{yy}$) the Schur complement lemma states that $P$ is p.d. iff $R$ is p.d..

So you definitely have an issue within MATLAB.